# XSL Transformation issue for an XML

Tags: xslt, saxparseexception

I am accessing a WebService which give me a valid response. While parsing the response using an XSL Transformation, I am getting SAXParseException. If I tested in the online tools such as freeformatter.com, I am getting a proper parsing without any issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The response I have received from the WebService is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><message channel-id="10a60e45-65d4-40c0-826f-1a91d2135da0">
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<ns:ITSPResponse xmlns:ns="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:BNYMDataITSPTest:Services">
<Output>Test IT Service Portal - 1</Output>
</ns:ITSPResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</message>
```

I am trying to parse the response using XSL Transformation; but receiving an exception. The XSL I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="urn:PegaRULES:SOAP:BNYMDataITSPTest:Services">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <message>
                <xsl:attribute name="channel-id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//@*[local-name()='channel-id']" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <send-parameters>
                    <agent-parameter>
                        <name>Output</name>
                        <value> <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='Output']" /> </value>
                    </agent-parameter>
                </send-parameters>
            </message>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The exception I am getting is

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file. at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124) at com.newscale.bfw.util.XMLValidator.validate(XMLValidator.java:147) at com.newscale.is.core.MessageExecutor.processNSTaskTransportMessage(MessageExecutor.java:135) at com.newscale.is.core.MessageExecutor.processTransportMessage(MessageExecutor.java:431) at com.newscale.is.core.MessageExecutor.processSynchronousOutboundMessage(MessageExecutor.java:526) at com.newscale.is.adk.OutboundAdapterUtil.processSynchronousResponse(OutboundAdapterUtil.java:44) at com.newscale.is.adapter.http.HTTPOutboundAdapter.call(HTTPOutboundAdapter.java:190) at com.newscale.is.adapter.http.HTTPOutboundAdapter.processMessage(HTTPOutboundAdapter.java:147) at com.newscale.is.core.MessageRouter.routeMessage(MessageRouter.java:115) at com.newscale.is.core.MessageExecutor.processOutboundMessage(MessageExecutor.java:604) at com.newscale.is.core.MessageExecutor.processMessage(MessageExecutor.java:125) at com.newscale.is.core.QueueListener.handleTextMessage(QueueListener.java:91) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:340) at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:237) at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:168) at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99) at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:73) at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:101) at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71) at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:115) at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:285) at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110) at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71) at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:322) at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:213) at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303) at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150) at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117) at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71) at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86) at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:105) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:561) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:499) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263) at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1059) at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1051) at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:948) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I am not sure whether I am missing anything anywhere?

Comment: The XML and XSL aren't useful information here. If the parser says your XML isn't well formed then it can't be parsing the document you have shown us. We need to see the Java code that is invoking the transformation process.

Comment: @Michael Kay, I'm not using Java code for parsing. I'm using a tool called "Cisco Prime Service Catalog" (CPSC), which sends the request to the WebService and get a response. I've posted the response along with the XSLT, I am using to parse the response. While receiving the response, CPSC validates the response XML and apply the XSLT on it. I believe that the parsing exception which I got is while validating the XML by the parser in CPSC. Noticed in Notepad++ while copying the reply - the attribute xmlns:xsd in <soap:Envelope> seems a root node - which could be a cause, i believe!

Comment: Sorry can't help any further. There's nothing wrong with the code you have shown us; therefore the problem is in code that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities: Either the document you're reading is ending unexpectedly (and is not well formed), or the stylesheet is ending unexpectedly (and is not well formed). The stylesheet is itself an XML document, after all, and can produce the same exceptions. Looking at the call stack for the exception may help you determine which is true. Running the program under a debugger might also help, by letting you see which URI the parser was trying to read from when it failed.

Or the exception could be coming from parsing some other part of your program and an XML document unrelated to this transformation. Again, look at the exception's call stack, or fire up the program under a debugger, to see what document is causing trouble.

If the parser tells you a file is ending prematurely, it's ending prematurely.